# spath3 causes Package pgfkeys Error with TeX Live 2020

Tags: tikz-pgf, texlive-2020

I would like to report an error that a user of mine has with a TeX (LaTeX) file my Python software creates. I am using the `spath3` package by Andrew Stacey to save and re-use a path. I **cannot** reproduce this error using my equipment:

- Windows 10 with MiKTeX Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 23.5)
- Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.3 LTS with TeX Live 2022

My user has:

- Debian with TeX Live **2020** (TeX Live 2020/Debian)

My software simply issues the command `pdflatex <filename>.tex` from Python on the generated `.tex` file. His setup with `TeX Live 2020/Debian` writes the following near the end of his `.log` file and fails to create a PDF file:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/spath/use', to which you 
passed 'PMdusk', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1033 [spath/use=PMdusk]
                         ; 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 17965 strings out of 481252
 373338 string characters out of 5915889
 979391 words of memory out of 5000000
 34602 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 410105 words of font info for 46 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 87i,8n,88p,1058b,1013s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

However - what I don't understand is that when he runs `pdflatex <filename>.tex` manually, *it succeeds and **creates a PDF file***. Perhaps it is an issue with available memory. As his equipment is on the other side of the Atlantic, I am unable to do any testing as well as being unable to reproduce it using TeX Live **2022**.

The key section from a sample `.tex` file that causes the problem is below. My apologies - please note that neither I nor my user are able to whittle this down to an MWE. With kind appreciation for `spath3` from Andrew Stacey.

```
% save PM dusk decoration path using the spath3 library
 \path[spath/save=PMdusk] plot[smooth,tension=0.5] coordinates{
(0.000, 11.995) (0.695, 12.099) (1.390, 12.220) (2.085, 12.349) (2.780, 12.481) 
(3.475, 12.611) (4.170, 12.738) (4.865, 12.860) (5.560, 12.982) (6.255, 13.103) 
(6.950, 13.226) (7.645, 13.352) (8.340, 13.480) (9.035, 13.605) (9.730, 13.725) 
(10.425, 13.829) (11.120, 13.909) (11.815, 13.957) (12.510, 13.965) (13.205, 13.931) 
(13.900, 13.856) (14.595, 13.745) (15.290, 13.604) (15.985, 13.440) (16.680, 13.259) 
(17.375, 13.069) (18.070, 12.874) (18.765, 12.681) (19.460, 12.496) (20.155, 12.324) 
(20.850, 12.172) (21.545, 12.044) (22.240, 11.949) (22.935, 11.890) (23.630, 11.870) 
(24.325, 11.892) (25.020, 11.951) (25.367, 11.993) };
% decorate PM dusk with text aligned left
\path [decorate,decoration={text along path,raise=-2.4ex,text align={left indent=1.112cm},text={|\PMstyle|D U S K~~~at latitude 40.0{°}N~~~(Sun 6{°} below horizon)}}]
[spath/use=PMdusk];
% decorate PM dusk with text aligned right
\path [decorate,decoration={text along path,raise=-2.4ex,text align={right, right indent=1.112cm},text={|\PMstyle|D U S K~~~at latitude 40.0{°}N~~~(Sun 6{°} below horizon)}}]
[spath/use=PMdusk];
```

P.S. I cannot find a `spath3` tag.

Comment: The `spath/use` key was introduced with version [2.4](https://github.com/loopspace/spath3/releases/tag/v2.4) (Feb 2021). A TeXLive 2020 installation won't have that version installed. Version 2.2 (early in the same month) has no mention of the `use` key and the newer manuals also explain that `use` is a generalization of many other keys. So, of course it doesn't work with TeXLive 2020.

Comment: The other thing might be that his manual `pdflatex …` call might use a different TeXLive version than Python's one because of search-path settings and whatnot. What does the start of the log files read? There should be a note about the version. (Or just `pdflatex -version`.)

Comment: Are both being run at the command line or is pdflatex being called by an editor? If the latter, the editor might be configured either to find a different TL or to use a different `TEXMFHOME` or to supplement the search path. If a more recent version is installed somewhere in `TEXMFHOME`, for example, you could get a later package version with earlier TL.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel An updated TL 2020 could well have a package from February 2021.

Comment: @cfr Oh, you're right, of course.  But then we really need to know OP's user's setup – as per your first comment.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - that explains it simply. (I saw no mention of possible dependencies in the v2.7 spath3 code manual so I wasn't expecting any.)